# What number should be here?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

I am trying to solve this quiz, but it is too hard for me.

What number should I put in place of the question mark?

```
3   6   2   8
2   1   1   3
1   3   1   4
5   5   3   ?
```

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!  Where did the quiz come from? - if you didn't create it yourself, could you provide attribution/ a link?

Comment: You edited this after accepting an answer, to change the puzzle to something different that invalidates the answer? Why?  If you have a new question to ask, ask it as a new question. See [the first paragraph of this answer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6257) for why changing answered questions is not good.  I've rolled back your change.

Comment: Also and has already been mentioned, it looks like you're asking us to solve a puzzle you found elsewhere. For content that you did not create yourself, please **[provide attribution](/help/referencing)** - at minimum you need to let us know where this came from, and any additional context you can provide is usually a big help to solvers. Posts which use someone else's content without disclosing where it came from are generally deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be

> 10

Because

> The numbers added to get the last column follow the pattern:
>
> ```
>  X X .
>
>  . X X
>
>  X X .
>
>  . X X
> ```

Comment: Austin, thank you! I consider that you are wright. I also think about 10.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> 8

with the idea that

> the final number in a row is the sum of the highest and lowest values in the rest of the columns in that row:
>  6+2 = 8
>  2+1 = 3
>  3+1 = 4
>  5+3 = **8**

Comment: Glorfindel, thank you for your answer! But Austin`s version is closer to the truth.